# Positioning of a table (tabularx)

Tags: tables, tabularx

I need to put a table in the right side of the page, how can I do it? (it should looks like in the picture). Here is code which I have right now.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{ucs}    
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[russian]{babel}     
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}   
\usepackage{tabularx}    
\begin{document}    

\begin{flushright}   
{\large {\textsc{Типова форма № П-4}}} \\   
{\large {\textsc{ЗАТВЕРДЖЕННО}}} \\   
{\large {\textsc{наказом Держкостату України}}} \\   
{\large {\textsc{від 5 грудня 2008 р. N 489}}} \\   
\end{flushright}   

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | X | X | }   
\hline    
ЄДРПОУ  & 21672519 \\ \hline    
Дата складання &  15.01.2016 \\  \hline   
\end{tabularx}    

\end{document}
```

[image: It needs loook like this:]

Comment: Try (i) replacing `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | X | X | }` with `\begin{tabularx}{0.25\textwidth}{ | X | X | }` and (b) moving the instruction `\end{flushright}` to *after* `\end{tabularx}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, if the following is what you looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[margin=30mm,showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \raggedleft
{    \large\scshape
Типова форма № П-4\\
ЗАТВЕРДЖЕННО\\
наказом Держкостату України\\
від 5 грудня 2008 р. N 489
}

\medskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | X | X | }
    \hline
ЄДРПОУ          &   21672519    \\ 
    \hline
Дата складання  &  15.01.2016   \\  
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```